# Is there any way we can compare Gatling report stats with previous execution and compare for any significant degradation?

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

I have been using Gatling and have been able to cover a lot of simulations for our APIs. But I could not figure out if a given API is being degraded or not.

And the only way is to compare it with previous runs. What all options are there in Gatling through which we can compare a report with the previous run ?

**For example -**

- A given simulation is taking 500 seconds
- Previously it was taking 400 seconds
- I should know about this degradation up front

Please share if anyone has idea about it.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: On the page of [Gatling FrontLine](https://gatling.io/gatling-frontline/): "You can trigger your tests, schedule them and get notified of any performance regressions.".

Comment: thanks for your response @GeorgeLeung, this is helpful